# Mapping of inner object values (JSON object) on single field in POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, automapper

I'm using Jackson for json mapping on java POJOs. What I want is to map inner fields of JSON to my parent java POJO and need to ask if it possible via any annotation or not ?  My JSON is as follows

```
{
        "email": "xyz@abc.com",
        "name": {
            "forenames": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
    }
}
```

and POJO is:

```
 public class CustomerVo {

        @JsonProperty("last4")
        private String emailAddress; 

        /*is there any annotation available that I can use to concat
        fornames and surname in 'customeName' ?? */
        private String customerName; 

    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if you have a `Name` object in your `CustomerVo`. If you do, you can implement a getter which will return `surname + forenames`.

Comment: You'd probably have to use a custom deserializer.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach But for that I will have to create a new class for Name {} That I don't wanna do and instead want to map forename and surname to CustomerVo's customerName

Comment: @Thomas How to do that ? for this specific case

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization first result of a quick google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could write a class `CustomerName` which will serialize your property. If you don't want to implement a seperate class, you need custom `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer` (btw: a bit more code than just writing the `CustomerName` class). For example,

```
public class CustomerNameJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String customerName, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        jg.writeStartObject();

        jg.writeFieldName("forenames");
        jg.writeString(/* extract your forenames from customerName */);

        jg.writeFieldName("surname");
        jg.writeString(/* extract your surname from customerName */);

        jg.writeEndObject();
    }

}

public class CustomerNameJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException {
        TreeNode tree = jp.readValueAsTree();
        TextNode forenames = (TextNode) tree.path("forenames");
        TextNode surname = (TextNode) tree.path("surname");

        return forenames.asText() + ":" + surname.asText();
    }

}

public class CustomerVo {

    @JsonProperty("last4")
    private String emailAddress; 

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomerNameJsonSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomerNameJsonDeserializer.class)
    private String customerName; 

}
```

Comment: you are correct it's bit more code. But thanks it was a learning curve for me and I appreciate your help. Just one question: can you mention any situation where I should consider using custom serializer instead of writing classes. I think when we have very complex json we should go with this else it's better to write classes ? make sense ?

Comment: @ManinGreen I use custom serializers when I want to serialize external objects from libraries (classes which I can not modify). When I serialize my own classes I usally don't use custom serializers. Creating corresponding classes give you more abstraction and control. In your example, you keep both properties `forenames` and `surname` in seperate properties. Then, you cannot mix them by accident.

Comment: @ManinGreen But, there is a use case: If you have very large lists of objects, you could use serializers to find a more compressed JSON notation.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `@JsonCreator` as it is said that

> `@JsonCreator`: annotation used for indicating that a constructor or
>   static factory method should be used for creating value instances
>   during deserialization.

Example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) 3.1. point. Documentation for [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations).